# Como consertar error de return Bool com Parse?

Tags: ios, swift

Quando vou compilar o código que o parse pede para colocar no appdelegate.swift aparece "return in function to return Bool" mas quando coloco return true, acontece mais de 30 erros e continua não funcionando, segue o código do appdelegate:

```swift
import UIKit

import Parse

import Bolts

@UIApplicationMain

class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

        Parse.enableLocalDatastore()

        // Initialize Parse.

        Parse.setApplicationId("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxj",

        clientKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx")

        PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions)

        return true

}
```

Comment: Ola Kroise, podes descrever mais sobre os erros que estão dando?

Comment: fala cara, então o que acontece e que aparecem depois que eu boto o "return true" erros como "audioServiesCreateSystem", "SCNetworkReachbility", "sqlite3_bind_blod" por ai @LucasEduardo

Comment: Se puder coloque todo o código do seu appDelegate para podermos analisar melhor, aparentemente não há problemas nesse trecho que você postou... a não ser o detalhe de estar faltando fechar a chave `}` da `func  didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

Comment: @iTSangar eu consegui resolver importando alguns frameworks, vlw pela ajuda!